# Deprecation warning on XGBoost - Sklearn

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, xgboost

I am using XGBClassifier() from XGBoost. I am getting the following deprecation warning.

Is there any solution to get rid of this warning ?

```
/home/carnd/anaconda3/envs/dl/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/cross_validation.py:44: DeprecationWarning: This module was deprecated in version 0.18 in favor of the model_selection module into which all the refactored classes and functions are moved. Also note that the interface of the new CV iterators are different from that of this module. This module will be removed in 0.20.
  "This module will be removed in 0.20.", DeprecationWarning)
```

After 2 hours in 64 GB CPU machine, it is still running. I am not sure whether the time it takes may be because of this deprecation warning or the just the length of the dataset.

Comment: It basically tells you what's going on: the cross_validation module is beeing removed/renamed. That's no problem for now, but your code will not run with later versions. I think it's now called model_selection. (the warning is not the source of your observation in regards of performance)

Comment: In this case, this tells that the `XGBClassifier` which is in the `xgboost` package, uses deprecated methods or classes of `scikit-learn` package.

Comment: Thanks guys. The model takes unusual time to run. that's why I posted this question. I know it is silly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is just a deprecation warning.

XGBClassifier uses deprecated functions of scikit-learn package.

Finally, if your performance is poor this is not the case. This message has nothing to do with the performance.

Answer (score 10):

This happens due to use_label_encoder which was used to encode the labels in sklearn.Since that is deprecated,you can set its value to False
`use_label_encoder =False`and run the classifier.
Also, this has no impact on the performance of the model, this will just remove user warning that comes while running XGBClassifier.

Answer (score 0):

For those being annoyed by this, simply remove it from your model. Example:

```
"XGBoost", XGBClassifier(use_label_encoder=False, eval_metric='logloss')
```

to:

```
"XGBoost", XGBClassifier(eval_metric='logloss')
```

No more warnings.